# In Mathematica, why is it that a replacement in a recursive function doesn't terminate?

Tags: recursion, replace, wolfram-mathematica

Imagine I've defined a recursive factorial in Mathematica, like this:

```
Clear[fact]
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_] := n fact[n - 1]
```

Evaluating fact[10] confirms that the function works and terminates.

A bit of a staple example, but it serves its purpose in this question. Actually, my question pertains to recursive function definitions in general anyway.

I expected evaluating the following replacement to terminate as well:

```
x fact[x-1] /. x -> 2
```

Alas, it runs in to a recursion depth limit:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
```

I expected to see something like:

```
2 fact[2-1]
```

or just the value

```
2
```

UPDATE: An alternative recursive definition of **fact** *does* work as expected:

```
Clear[fact]
fact[n_] := If[n < 1, 1, n fact[n - 1]]
```

But this fact (pun intended ;-) makes it even more mysterious to me: Why does it behave so much differently?

My question is twofold:

1. Even with the built-in help and searching the net for clues, I can't explain why Mathematica insists in, apparently, keeping the symbolic result, rather than evaluating the 'intermediate' results and terminating nicely. Who ventures a viable explaination?
2. How can I convince Mathematica to perform according to my expections (Other than using the alternative using **If**[])?

I'm really puzzled by this one, and I really hope someone out there can help me out.

/Twan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying `u[x_] := x; Trace[x*u[x] /. x -> 2]`, it first evaluates `x` and `u[x]`. In your case, then, it first tries to evaluate `fact[x-1]` before replacing `x` by 2, and hits the recursion limit.

`Attributes[ReplaceAll]` shows that it does not have attribute `HoldFirst`, so it starts by evaluating its first argument. For instance,

```
ReleaseHold@ReplaceAll[Hold[x*fact[x - 1]], x -> 2]
```

gives the expected `2`, as it holds the first argument, replaces, then releases the hold, as you intended.

Another way to do it is

```
Unprotect[ReplaceAll]
SetAttributes[ReplaceAll, HoldFirst]
ReplaceAll[x*fact[x - 1], x -> 2]
```

but don't do this.

Surely someone will give a better explanation soon, though.

EDIT: In response to the added question as to why

```
Clear[factif]
factif[n_] := If[n < 1, 1, n factif[n - 1]]
```

does not result in infinite recursion: defined this way, `factif[x]` evaluates to `If[x < 1, 1, x factif[x - 1]]`, since `x<1` cannot be evaluated. So it remains in this form after the attempted evaluation of the first argument of `ReplaceAll`, then the replacement occurs etc.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense: Mathematica first evaluates the LHS of /. and _then_ performs the replacement. And with Hold[] you can postpone that 'eager' evaluation. Thanks for the great answer: effective, relevant, clear and succinct! My compliments

Comment: @nanitous Cheers! If one of the three answers does answer your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer so that it then appears at the top (and it gives a reputation boost to the answerer).

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're evaluating this:

```
fact[x-1]
```

before the replacement happens. Just do `fact[x-1]` and you get the error.

You can fix your `fact` function like so:

```
Clear[fact]
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_Integer?Positive] := n fact[n - 1]
```

Then `x fact[x - 1] /. x -> 2` returns `2` which seems correct.

Remember that your function argument pattern `fact[n_]` is *extremely* general. For example it allows for something like `fact[Integrate[Sin[x], x]]` to evaluate, which is probably not something you intended. Using `fact[n_Integer]` is much more precise, and will allow the `fact` function to act the way you want it to.

If you want to define this function even better, you can do something like:

```
Clear[fact]
fact::nicetrybuddy = "fact[``] is not defined.";
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_Integer?Positive] := n fact[n - 1]
fact[n_] := (Message[fact::nicetrybuddy, n]; $Failed)
```

So that something like `fact["x"]` will fail with a message:

```
fact::nicetrybuddy: fact[x] is not defined.
```

Comment: Nice idea to add a catch-all clause! I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct: `fact` evaluates before its argument is replaced. The essential issue is that you have defined `fact` with integer inputs in mind, and haven't provided a terminal condition for non-integer inputs. If you instead did

```
Clear[fact]
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_Integer?Positive] := n fact[n - 1]
```

Then `fact` would be left unevaluated until it had something that matched a positive integer.

You might need to wrap your replacement statement in `Evaluate` to then fire the definition for `fact` after replacing its argument.

An alternative approach might be to use a pure function:

```
# fact[#-1]& @ 2
```

That shouldn't evaluate prematurely.

Comment: I'm running a big simulation right now (400,000 Hodrick-Prescott filters!) so I haven't checked that last suggestion with the pure function.

Comment: I considered this. But I've experimented with different recursive functions, e.g. for lists. And I met the same behaviour. So I posted the question as general as I could. But an example does make things specific again. Sorry for that.